# Replace one string with another using Angular.js or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some JSON data and I need to replace one value with another string using Angular.js or JavaScript. My code is below:

```
$http({
    method:'POST',
    url:"php/getFilterCodeData.php",
    data:filterData,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(function successCallback(response){
    console.log('filter',response.data);
    $scope.last=[];
    for(var i=0;i<response.data.length;i++){
       $scope.arrCode=response.data[i].generated_code.split(',');
    }
        //console.log('arr',$scope.arrCode);
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.arrCode.length;i++){
        $scope.last.push($scope.arrCode[i].split("_").pop());
    }
    //console.log('last',$scope.last);
    var newStr=$scope.last[0]+"-"+$scope.last[$scope.last.length-1];

    //console.log('new str',newStr);
},function errorCallback(response) {
})
```

Here I am getting the below data using console:

```
filter [{
customer_name: "Big-Bazar"
expired_date: "23-12-2015"
generated_code: "medilink_global_01,medilink_global_02,medilink_global_03,medilink_global_04,medilink_global_05,medilink_global_06,medilink_global_07,medilink_global_08,medilink_global_09,medilink_global_10,medilink_global_11,medilink_global_12,medilink_global_13,medilink_global_14,medilink_global_15,medilink_global_16,medilink_global_17,medilink_global_18,medilink_global_19,medilink_global_20,medilink_global_21,medilink_global_22,medilink_global_23,medilink_global_24,medilink_global_25,medilink_global_26,medilink_global_27,medilink_global_28,medilink_global_29,medilink_global_30,medilink_global_31,medilink_global_32,medilink_global_33,medilink_global_34,medilink_global_35,medilink_global_36,medilink_global_37,medilink_global_38,medilink_global_39,medilink_global_40"
no_of_voucher: "40"
status: "generated"
voucher_amount: "3000"
voucher_code_id: "13"}]
```

Here I need to replace the `generated_code:` value with `newStr`. The expected output should be:

```
generated_code:01-40
```

Comment: What is the problem? what thing you don't know? What is the expected output?

Comment: in the for cycle: `response.data[i].generated_code = newStr;` voila

Comment: The exepected output should be `generated_code:01-40` in this case.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because this question is about replacing a property _value_, while the answers to the other question are mostly about replacing property _names_.

Answer (score 2):

In the Javascript:

```
$scope.filter = filter;
$scope.filter[0].generate_code = newStr;
```

To show the string, just use `{{ filter[0].generate_code }}` in your template.

AngularJS always watches changes to variables in the scope and will replace them in the template as they change, so it's pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

you do it like this:

```
response.data[i].generated_code=newStr;
```